VSCode Gemini Code assistant failed to load
My Gemini Code Assistant in VSCode used to suggest code, even if it wasn't always helpful. But a few days ago, it stopped working entirely. Clicking the start button brings up a chat window, but nothing happens when I type anything in it.
After investigating in 'Tasks' output I notice that error is:
mainThreadExtensionService.ts:81 [googlecloudtools.cloudcode]The "this" argument must be an instance of Performance. Received [Object]
Somehow it complains about this argument and it seems to be main reason why it is stop working..
After I try to restart/update/install/uninstall the extension now it could not even 'Login to Google Cloud' as in this screenshot with the same error.

May be someone knows a workaround ? I already update Nodejs to the latest. I am running on Windows 11. Visual Studio Code Insiders version is:
Version: 1.90.0-insider (user setup)
Commit: 5e68ffd760038bb156894a87f896910be510accd
Date: 2024-05-15T08:29:12.858Z (11 hrs ago)
Electron: 29.3.1
ElectronBuildId: 9464424
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631


thanks for reporting this bug, this issue should now be fixed on 2.11.3.
